# TcpListener does not contain a definition for "AcceptSocket"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tcpclient, tcpserver

[This is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0wT8.png)While I was writing TcpClient-Server Program in Vs2017 following issues came.

```
Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");     
Socket s=myList.AcceptSocket();
Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);`
```

It says that the TcpListner does not contain a does not contain such method. 
Please help. Full code can be found at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C

Thanks and Regards,
T.S.

Comment: did you miss out the namespace `using System.Net.Sockets;` or `using System.Net`. I've tested the code on VS2015. No errors at all. Kindly re-check your code.

Comment: you still getting error ?

Comment: Hi active92, Can you please gimme a link as I was trying this at .net Core which might not be the IDE to run it.

Comment: @TonyStark a link? what do you mean? i just copied and paste the code from the link that you've provided.

Comment: Yes the error still persists

Comment: @Active92. I'm actually new to C# as I'm a Java and J2EE developer. So can you tell me where should I copy & paste this code? What I was doing was Templates -> Visual C# -> .NET Core -> Console App Is it correct. Please view https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0wT8.png for screenshot

Comment: @Tony Stark. Your code looks fine.

Comment: Ah.. Okay bro :-) Problem solved. Instead of using Black Console IDE what I was using is .NET Core

Comment: @TonyStark good to hear that it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening in above code is Instead of using .NET Framework Console app what was using was .NET Core which isn't the compatible one which gave the error. The reason was that MS site was using .NET Core for all previous programs and though same for this.